# R t-test of mean vs observations for multiple factor levels

Tags: r, apply

I have a dataset of some 39k rows of data, an excerpt is below:

- 'Country', 'Group', 'Item', 'Year' are categorical
- 'Production' and 'Waste' are numerical
- 'LF' is also numerical, but is the result of 'Waste'/'Production

  ```
  Region  Country Group   Item    Year    Production  Waste   LF
  Europe  Bulgaria    Cereals Wheat   1961    2040    274 0.134313725
  Europe  Bulgaria    Cereals Wheat   1962    2090    262 0.125358852
  Europe  Bulgaria    Cereals Wheat   1963    1894    277 0.14625132
  Europe  Bulgaria    Cereals Wheat   1964    2121    286 0.134842056
  Europe  Bulgaria    Cereals Wheat   1965    2923    341 0.116660965
  Europe  Bulgaria    Cereals Wheat   1966    3193    385 0.120576261
  Europe  Bulgaria    Cereals Barley  1961    612 15  0.024509804
  Europe  Bulgaria    Cereals Barley  1962    599 16  0.026711185
  Europe  Bulgaria    Cereals Barley  1963    618 16  0.025889968
  Europe  Bulgaria    Cereals Barley  1964    764 21  0.027486911
  Europe  Bulgaria    Cereals Barley  1965    876 22  0.025114155
  Europe  Bulgaria    Cereals Barley  1966    1064    24  0.022556391
  ```

I have used the following code to generate 991 different means by Item and Group

```
df2 <- aggregate(LF ~ Country + Item, data=df1, FUN='mean')
```

The results of this function look ok.

I would like to test whether the respective means of LF in df2 are different to the underlying annual observations in df1 for each Country-Item combination (ie. if FALSE, then LF is really just a static ratio, if TRUE then 'Waste' is independent from 'Production').

How might this best be done? There seem to be 991 tests to conduct for this dataset alone and I don't know how to mix the `apply` and `t.test` functions in this manner.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

t.test requires two groups to compare on a numeric/scale dependent output variable. Here, it seems to me that for each combination of country and item you want to compare all different year averages/means. In other words, you are trying to investigate if year is influencing the LF averages, for each combination of country and item.

The easiest way to do this is to create a linear model (LF ~ Year) for each combination of country and item and interpret the coefficient and p value of the variable year.

```
library(dplyr)
library(broom)

set.seed(115)

# example dataset
dt = data.frame(Country = rep("country1",12),
                Item = c(rep("item1",6), rep("item2",6)),
                Year = rep(1961:1966,2),
                LF = runif(12,0,1))

# general means by country and item
dt %>% group_by(Country,Item) %>% summarise(Mean_LF = mean(LF))

# each years means by country and item
dt %>% group_by(Country,Item,Year) %>% summarise(Mean_LF = mean(LF))

# does year influence the means for each country and item?
dt %>% group_by(Country,Item) %>% do(tidy(lm(LF~Year, data=.)))
```

Hope this helps. Let me know if I'm missing something and I'll update my code.